# Constrain type while still preserving original type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jss

```
import { CSSProperties } from 'react';
type StyleRulesType = Partial<CSSProperties>

type StylesDefinition = { [key: string]: StyleRulesType };


const styles: StylesDefinition = {
    list: {
        position: 'relative',
    },
    listCount: {
        fontStyle: 'italic'
    }
}

type StyleKeys = keyof typeof styles;
```

I am trying to constrain styles to only contain children of CSSProperties labels and values, this is working through the StylesDefinition constraint.

I am trying to have Keys be 'list' | 'listitem', this works when styles isn't constrained by StylesDefinition.

I want to constrain to help populating stylevariables and values, at the same time I want to be able to get type checking when referencing the styles object so that I can only use styles.list and styles.listCount

Happy to introduce further types and methods to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't both constrain the type of a variable and have its type inferred. The usual way to do this is to use a function, which can have a type parameter that is both constrained and inferred:

```
import { CSSProperties } from 'react';
type StyleRulesType = Partial<CSSProperties>

type StylesDefinition = { [key: string]: StyleRulesType };
function createStyleDefinition<T extends StylesDefinition>(o: T) {
    return o;
}

const styles = createStyleDefinition({
    list: {
        position: 'relative',
    },
    listCount: {
        fontStyle: 'italic'
    }
})

type StyleKeys = keyof typeof styles;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=18&ssc=39&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYQMqoApQmAprYXAZzgF84AzbEOAcilwEMBjGWgbgCgYBPPOVLwA2uAEoBXEUQAqfXHAC8cDIwKMhAHjSZseAsQB8nbnIHDiAEVwVgAO2AxgEW4sRwA2gGtcPAFxwiGCg7AHMAXX9BHhEJKVl+Ui4KcVtWJxdmBkYYXCiRKxt7R2cNaThcAA8c2wATEjzLazsHdIMACgh-aQBKRE44AbgGGHEoFwguUmNmZ0CA8xIlTKYchoLm4ts2hH7BoWBA-x3Bk7hIIhbnf3pcIWzgADdcWgAaXYHSN5P9wOQIFJgR3epwozhgDWuDnUwGYtGBU1I3WMvH4DQA0j5FnBvDwIBQ4CjcHj5tFiOw4EA)